# search and replace multi-line text with white space

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

I am trying to search for some text in a XML file, the text is:

```
</p_dpopis>
    <IMGURL>
```

And replace it with:

```
</p_dpopis>
<p_vyrobce>NONAME</p_vyrobce>
    <IMGURL>
```

Here is what I tried with perl, without any luck:

```
perl -0pe 's|</p_dpopis>.*\n.*<IMGURL>|replacement|' myxml.xml
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you searched for other perl questions on multiline matching? There are only about five million on SO...

Comment: Do you need a multiline match? Does `</p_dpopsis>` appear in other places in the file?

Comment: There is also some very useful documentation on the perl website, such as [search and replace from the perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a 'global' modifier for your regex, and using `\s+` to match any amount of whitespace is much easier than specifying `.*\n.*`. It's also nicer to send the output to another file, rather than having to deal with it in the terminal window.

```
perl -0pe 's|</p_dpopis>\s+<IMGURL>|</p_dpopis>\n<p_vyrobce>NONAME</p_vyrobce>\n<IMGURL>|g' myxml.xml > my_new_xml.xml
```

If you're manipulating XML, it is really better to use a dedicated XML parser -- you can get into all sorts of mischief by manipulating an irregular language such as XML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax works:

```
$ cat file
</p_dpopis>
    <IMGURL>
$ perl -0pe 's|</p_dpopis>.*\n.*<IMGURL>|replacement|g' file
replacement
```

Here is a `sed` example with the same example file:

```
$ sed -r '/<\/p_dpopis>/{ N; s%</p_dpopis>.*\n.*<IMGURL>%replaced\ntest%g }' file
replaced
test
```

See this [reference](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/27/20-Multi-line-sed-search-and-replace/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @zerodiff, I am now trying to do this with sed (I found it is faster). This regex is matched on regex101.com, but does not work in sed? What's wrong here: sed -r -e 's/<\/p_dpopis>.*\n\s\s\s\s<IMGURL>/miez/g' xy.xml

Comment: @ialarmedalien I am on the way :-) http://regex101.com/r/tV4jJ8/1 Only sed does not want to be working/replace relevant parts.

Comment: I added a `sed` example and a link.